# How to update Aspect metadata in alfresco using c# do net code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, alfresco, aspect, alfresco-webscripts

In alfresco I have created a custom aspect (ex. studentAspect). In my asp.net site, I wanna apply this aspect on a specific document and update the metadata values (ex. studentName, studentGrdae...etc) using any type of integration (ex. dotCMIS, calling RESTful API.

Any help would be highly appreciated
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Either of the two integration methods you should do it, amongst others. What did you try? Which tutorials did you follow? What code did you write? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: hi, I tried dotcmis and couldn't do it because it doesn't support aspect.

Comment: couldn't find any other way to do it using asp.net

Comment: Use PortCMIS, which is CMIS 1.1 and therefore does Aspects properly via [secondary types](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/pra/1/concepts/cmis-1.1-using-aspects.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the edit-metadata restful webscript.
For further info please check [Alfresco wiki](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Repository_RESTful_API_Reference#Node_Metadata_Storage_Service)